# Seeing intermittent long ACK times in Kafka Producer (10 seconds)

Tags: java, linux, networking, apache-kafka

We have three Kafka brokers version 1.1.1 on c5.4xlarge AWS instances. There is currently about 750 topics and about 1800 partitions. For certain reasons we cannot upgrade soon. One team connected to these brokers has mentioned that occasionally, the time to receive an ACK (with `acks=1`) takes over 10 seconds. The p95 response time of the ACKS is about 11ms.  I'm a bit confused as to what could be causing this.

We are running the following version of Java

```
openjdk version "1.8.0_382"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_382-b05)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.382-b05, mixed mode)
```

You can see the delay on the producer side in these logs.  This is a test producer that sends messages synchronously by waiting on the future with `send().get()`, through the Kafka Spring client.

```
2023-12-05 19:27:15.036 TRACE 1664 --- [ | TestProducer] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=TestProducer] Nodes with data ready to send: [kafka1:6667 (id: 1001 rack: us-west-2a)]
2023-12-05 19:27:15.036 TRACE 1664 --- [ | TestProducer] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=TestProducer] Sent produce request to 1001: (type=ProduceRequest, acks=1, timeout=30000, partitionRecords=({test-producer-2=[(record=DefaultRecord(offset=0, timestamp=1701804435036, key=0 bytes, value=3 bytes))]}), transactionalId=''
2023-12-05 19:27:25.062 TRACE 1664 --- [ | TestProducer] o.a.k.clients.producer.internals.Sender  : [Producer clientId=TestProducer] Received produce response from node 1001 with correlation id 59645
2023-12-05 19:27:25.062 TRACE 1664 --- [ | TestProducer] o.a.k.c.p.internals.ProducerBatch        : Successfully produced messages to test-producer-2 with base offset 283532.
2023-12-05 19:27:25.062  INFO 1664 --- [   scheduling-1] com.company.kafkatest.Service             : Publish completed in 10025ms, Start: 2023-12-05T19:27:15.036Z, End: 2023-12-05T19:27:25.062Z. Metadata test-producer-2@283532
```

On the broker side, we can see the request log which was entered at `2023-12-05 13:27:25.062`

```
Completed request:RequestHeader(apiKey=PRODUCE, apiVersion=5, clientId=TestProducer, correlationId=59645) -- {acks=1,timeout=30000,numPartitions=1},response:{responses=[{topic=produce-test,partition_responses=[{partition=2,error_code=0,base_offset=283532,log_append_time=-1,log_start_offset=91996}]}],throttle_time_ms=0} from connection 10.0.0.13:6667-[redacted broker IP]:37072-52576;totalTime:15.921,requestQueueTime:0.025,localTime:0.51,remoteTime:0.0,throttleTime:0.017,responseQueueTime:15.174,sendTime:0.213,securityProtocol:SASL_OAUTHBEARER,principal:User:[redacted],listener:SASL_OAUTHBEARER (kafka.request.logger)
```

Here are some of the non-default configs we have on the broker side:

```
num.partitions=3
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=32

# replica timings
max.incremental.fetch.session.cache.slots=20000
replica.lag.time.max.ms=90000
num.replica.fetchers=8
num.io.threads=16
num.network.threads=32
heartbeat.interval.ms=9000
session.timeout.ms=30000
```

The producer using library version `1.1.1` is using all the defaults and `acks=1`. Here is the producer config that is printed in the logs:

```
2023-12-05 19:24:58.971  INFO 1664 --- [   scheduling-1] o.a.k.clients.producer.ProducerConfig    : ProducerConfig values:
        acks = 1
        batch.size = 16384
        bootstrap.servers = [kafka1:6667, kafka2:6667, kafka3:6667]
        buffer.memory = 33554432
        client.id = TestProducer
        compression.type = none
        connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
        enable.idempotence = false
        interceptor.classes = []
        key.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
        linger.ms = 0
        max.block.ms = 60000
        max.in.flight.requests.per.connection = 5
        max.request.size = 1048576
        metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
        metric.reporters = []
        metrics.num.samples = 2
        metrics.recording.level = INFO
        metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
        partitioner.class = class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner
        receive.buffer.bytes = 32768
        reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
        reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
        request.timeout.ms = 30000
        retries = 0
        retry.backoff.ms = 100
        sasl.jaas.config = [hidden]

        [removed some sasl configs]

        sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
        sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
        sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
        sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
        sasl.mechanism = OAUTHBEARER
        security.protocol = SASL_OAUTHBEARER
        send.buffer.bytes = 131072
        ssl.cipher.suites = null
        ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
        ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = null
        ssl.key.password = null
        ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
        ssl.keystore.location = null
        ssl.keystore.password = null
        ssl.keystore.type = JKS
        ssl.protocol = TLS
        ssl.provider = null
        ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
        ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
        ssl.truststore.location = null
        ssl.truststore.password = null
        ssl.truststore.type = JKS
        transaction.timeout.ms = 60000
        transactional.id = null
        value.serializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
```

Also, for the JVM options, we are using:

```
KAFKA_HEAP_OPTS="-Xmx4G -Xms4G"
KAFKA_JVM_PERFORMANCE_OPTS="-server -XX:+UseCompressedOops -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+CMSScavengeBeforeRemark -XX:+DisableExplicitGC -Djava.awt.headless=true"
```

Note that the CPU usage on these brokers usually sits around 3%, and the load is almost non-existent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending quite a lot of time debugging this issue, it appears the delay was caused by a DNS lookup timeout. It seems Kafka version 1.1.1 does a hostname lookup for all new connections. Certain clients from certain data centers were connecting to our brokers. Kafka would timeout when doing a hostname lookup from these data centers that do not have DNS entries. The lookup would time out and cause a delay for all other connections on that thread.

Our solution was to reduce the timeout to 1 second as well as use the JVM option `networkaddress.cache.negative.ttl` to cache failed lookups. See the following issue for more details: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-8562

This will for for us until we can update Kafka to a newer version. I understand that newer versions of Kafka do not have this issue as the DNS lookup was removed.

Answer (score 0):

Since your 95th Percentile Response time is 11ms I highly doubt this has anything to do with Apache Kafka Brokers.

This could be due to your Kafka Broker Auth mechanism. Since SASL_OAUTHBEARER is used there can be delays when the OAUTH token is expired and a new token needs to be fetched.

There are ways to proactively refresh these tokens to avoid such delays.

You can go through Apache Kafka [documentation](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/kafka/authentication_sasl/authentication_sasl_oauth.html) to try to configure it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but we have root caused the problem to a DNS issue.  I'll explain in an answer.